# Airflow issue with unique behavior related to trigger rules

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow DAG that ends with a dummy task called "End".

directly upstream to the "End" task, there are four tasks that run in parallel.

I try to achieve a situation where the "End" task will be successful even if one of these four tasks fails. Having saying that, if any of the upstream tasks in the dag that are prior to these four tasks fail, I want the End task to fail as well - effectively failing the DAG.

How can I achieve that?

I tried setting End with "all_done" but this will make this task to succeed even if upstream tasks to the direct four parent tasks fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all_done is not status sensitive, it just wants all upstream tasks complete.

Do the immediate 4 tasks run regardless of upstream failures? If they fail if any of their upstream fail, you could set the trigger rule to none_failed for the end task.
Otherwise, I don't think trigger rules alone are going to get you want you need as they only pay attention to their direct upstream tasks. You will probably want to keep all_done as the trigger rule, but you will need to make a python operator for the end task that recursively navigates the DAG tree and throws an error on the conditions you outlined.